# CSV from_writer works on stdout(), but fails on from_path

Tags: rust, serde

Rust beginner here.

I've been trying to learn the CSV crate but got stuck on the following case.

My goal is to:

1. Parse a nested array
2. Set column names to array values
3. Write to CSV

Firstly here is the code that outputs exactly what I want it to.

```rust
use serde::Serialize;
use serde::Deserialize;
use csv;
use serde_json;
use std::io;

#[derive(Debug,Serialize,Deserialize)]
#[serde(transparent)]
struct Parent {
    arr_field: Vec<Row>
}

#[derive(Debug,Serialize,Deserialize)]
struct Row {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
    c: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let resp = r#" [[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,5,6]] "#;
    let mut wtr = csv::WriterBuilder::new().from_writer(io::stdout());

    let v: Parent = serde_json::from_str(resp).unwrap();

    for row in v.arr_field{
        wtr.serialize(row);
    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
3,2,1
4,5,6
```

But when I want to save the output to a local file rather than stdout, like so:

```rust
    let mut wtr = csv::WriterBuilder::new().from_path("./foo.csv");
```

I'm getting the following error at `wtr.serialize`

```
error[E0599]: no method named `serialize` found for enum `std::result::Result<Writer<File>, csv::Error>` in the current scope
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just got it, needed to use `.unwrap()` on the from_path method, because it can fail, and we need to tell rust what to do with that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you all you need to know - [`from_path`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.5/csv/struct.WriterBuilder.html#method.from_path) returns a `Result` rather than a `WriterBuilder`, because opening that file might not always work. That is different with `from_writer` - no file needs to be opened, so no possibility of encountering an error.

To fix this, you can just use `.unwrap()`, like you do with `serde_json::from_str` the line below. This will cause a panic when an error was encountered, immediately terminating your program.

```rust
let mut wtr = csv::WriterBuilder::new().from_path("./foo.csv").unwrap();
```

Note that [`serialize`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.5/csv/struct.Writer.html#method.serialize) also returns a result, so you should also add `.unwrap()` or some other logic to handle errors in your for loop. Rust will likely show a warning that there is an unused result.